# What is the best way to monetize Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

This might be very simple question but how do people monetize Facebook app? Do they just display ad within their apps using Google Adsense or similar services? Does Facebook have a service to monetize your app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Here is list of [facebook approved advertisers](http://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/).
2. If you can charge people some [Facebook Credit](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=837) (Virtual Currency) from your users it will be a big source of revenue. You can read the policy of signing up and [redeeming the facebook credits](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/).
3. Use [rockyou media publisher platform](https://www.rockyoumedia.com/developers/)
4. Google TSO doesnt' allow you to put ads in iFrame so google may bad you if you do that apps which are iframes. moreover AdSense is not in facebook approved list of advertisers (menationed in point 1)

Comment: Can you convert Facebook Credit back to cash? If yes, how?

Comment: You can convert it to $$. That how big companies like Zynga makes money. Just edited the answer about redemption of Facebook credits.